Firefox and Chrome browsers are giving me false information about HTTPv3 over QUIC
I had a bit of a problem to properly identify HTTPv3 over QUIC support on my IIS Web Server.
When I open Firefox - Developer Tools and I access my IIS site I see that requests under "Network" are on protocol HTTPv3 which is fine. However when I check Page Info - Technical Details I see than Connection is encrypted by TLS 1.3 and not QUIC which doesn't make sense.
When I open Chrome - Developer Tools and I access my IIS site I see that requests under "Network" are on protocol HTTPv2 which is not okay. However when I check "Security" I see that Connection is encrypted via QUIC.
Does this make any sense at all? Is there any way how to properly validate HTTPv3 over QUIC on my IIS?
Here is a printscreen from Firefox:

Here is a printscreen from Chrome:



Connection is encrypted by TLS 1.3 and not QUIC which doesn't make sense

On the contrary, QUIC by itself doesn't negotiate encryption. Instead, the current version of the QUIC transport protocol literally embeds TLS 1.3 as its encryption mechanism. See RFC 9000 (section 7), RFC 9001.

Okay got it. This explain the first half and that's why Firefox is showing TLSv1.3 instead of QUIC. It's seems to be this way because Firefox (at least for now) doesn't show you QUIC protocol under Page Info, only TLS version.
However this doesn't explain the second part - Why Chrome is showing protocol httpv2 when using QUIC?
